# How to deploy a signal R self host server on azure web app

Tags: c#, azure, signalr

I am new to azure and I have an web app running on Azure web app and I have my signal-R self host as an console application. I want to deploy the signal r self host conbsole app to azure. What are the steps I need to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@esther fang,

please reference below tutorial, one thing need to be aware is, you will need to manually enable web socket for you site.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/using-signalr-with-azure-web-sites

Quote:

> Deploying a SignalR Web App to Azure App Service
>
> SignalR doesn't add any particular complications to deploying an
>   application to Azure versus deploying to an on-premises server. An
>   application that uses SignalR can be hosted in Azure without any
>   changes in configuration or other settings (though for WebSockets
>   support, see Enabling WebSockets on Azure App Service below.) For this
>   tutorial, you'll deploy the application created in the Getting Started
>   Tutorial to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can host your console application on Azure as Web or Worker Role or even on a virtual machine managed by you. 
[Here](http://cloudmonix.com/blog/what-is-web-and-worker-role-in-microsoft-azure/) is a blog post comparing Azure Web and Worker Roles.

You can find the steps you have to take in order to set it up in the following answer:

[Hosting console application on Azure or Amazon, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713073/2528907)