# SignalR Working Flawlessly on Local , but not working on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, react-redux, signalr

Everything is working smoothly on my localhost but when  I Deployed my app on azure (HTTP) it doesn't work. I have tried different scenarios :

a ) persistent connections, 
 b) adding this code :

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="1800" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Note: I have enabled the websockets in my azure app service so that isn't the problem. I am using a react-redux app as a frontend and a Asp.net MVC5 as a backend. On Azure I am not using a Virtual machine . Only an App Service

In localhost , the signalR uses websockets but for some reason it fails in azure then it results to longpolling , based from the log:

[Log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMKUq.png)
[Log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1xzN.png)

The Client Called the server method , and the server called the client method as well , but after that the connection is lost. The SignalR will automatically try to reconnect but still it will result to a timeout, any thoughts about this?

Q1 : Why Is the websocket failing on azure?
Q2 : in long polling : Why is it going on timeout ? 
Q3 : in Long polling : why can't it reconnect ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: *In localhost , the signalR uses websockets but for some reason it fails in azure then it results to longpolling , based from the log:*, is the [port for SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38275291/4648586) opened yet? and azure.. apparently had [signalr sdk and subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core)...

Comment: I am using , Asp.net MVC5 not Core...

Comment: And Yes , it is opened , as you can see in the Logs , it successfully called the hub from client -> server then server back to the client. But then it disconnects and for some reason it cannot reconnect...

Comment: I hope you understand that SignalR is extremely resource intensive because of all of the connections your backend needs to maintain. Verify your app service is configured on a tier to be able to support this and monitory CPU/memory usage to see if this is causing connections to drop. Lastly, consider the use of the Azure SignalR Managed Service if you are targeting Azure for your SignalR/Web App solution.